# After activating, inactive integral, output is coming same as input

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, hold

I am trying to plot s w.r.t r (0,10). But because of inactive integral I am not able to. When I activate inactive integral, output is coming same as input. When I am trying to plot graph w.r.t r(0 to 10), I am unable to plot graph because of inactive integral. Any idea how to solve this will help me a lot.

```
s=1/(1331 r) 98 (r^2 (-3 + 
      2 r) (-11 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, (7 r)/
        11] + 10 r Hypergeometric2F1[1 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 1 + 2 Sqrt[5/7],
         3, (7 r)/11]) + 
   3 r^2 ((143 - 88 r) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
        2, (7 r)/11] + 
      5 r (-5 + 3 r) Hypergeometric2F1[1 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
        1 + 2 Sqrt[5/7], 3, (7 r)/
        11])) (5324/(147 (77 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 
          2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, 7/11] + 
        r^2 (11 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, 7/
             11] - 10 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
             1 + 2 Sqrt[5/7], 3, 7/11]) - 
        10 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 1 + 2 Sqrt[5/7], 3, 7/
          11])) - Inactive[Integrate][(
    121 (2842 (36 - 5 I \[Pi] + 
          5 Log[-10 + 9 K[1]]) MeijerG[{{}, {3 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           3 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{1, 2}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] + 
       252 I (341 I + 65 \[Pi] + 
          65 I Log[-10 + 9 K[1]]) MeijerG[{{}, {4 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           4 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{2, 3}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] - 
       34749 MeijerG[{{}, {5 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 5 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{3, 
           4}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11]))/(
    11907 (-11 + 
       7 K[1]) (14 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, (
         7 K[1])/11] MeijerG[{{}, {4 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           4 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{2, 3}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] - 
       10 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 1 + 2 Sqrt[5/7], 3, (
         7 K[1])/11] MeijerG[{{}, {5 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           5 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{3, 4}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] - 
       7 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, (7 K[1])/
         11] MeijerG[{{1}, {4 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 4 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{2, 
           3}, {2}}, (7 K[1])/11])), {K[1], 1, 1}] + 
   Inactive[Integrate][(
    121 (2842 (36 - 5 I \[Pi] + 
          5 Log[-10 + 9 K[1]]) MeijerG[{{}, {3 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           3 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{1, 2}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] + 
       252 I (341 I + 65 \[Pi] + 
          65 I Log[-10 + 9 K[1]]) MeijerG[{{}, {4 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           4 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{2, 3}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] - 
       34749 MeijerG[{{}, {5 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 5 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{3, 
           4}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11]))/(
    11907 (-11 + 
       7 K[1]) (14 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, (
         7 K[1])/
         11] MeijerG[{{}, {4 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 4 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{2, 
           3}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] - 
       10 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 1 + 2 Sqrt[5/7], 3, (
         7 K[1])/11] MeijerG[{{}, {5 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 
           5 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{3, 4}, {}}, (7 K[1])/11] - 
       7 Hypergeometric2F1[-2 Sqrt[5/7], 2 Sqrt[5/7], 2, (7 K[1])/
         11] MeijerG[{{1}, {4 - 2 Sqrt[5/7], 4 + 2 Sqrt[5/7]}}, {{2, 
           3}, {2}}, (7 K[1])/11])), {K[1], 1, r}])
```

Comment: One of your integral is from 1 to 1, so it is zero (?), the second is from 1 to `r`, but you want plot with `{r, 0, 10}`. Is everything correct with your `s`? And general advice not using `Inactive[Integrate]` (why do you use this?), but use numerical integration with `NIntegrate` with appropriate bounds: `s1[r_?NumericQ]:= ... NIntegrate[...] ...`.

Comment: Yeah. Integration from 1 to 1 is zero. I have not used inactive integration. When I solved the equation I got this as an output. Do I need to use any function for that